# How to create object of same type and assign value to it in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am assigning a value to a variable of same data type. Like this:

[image]

The issue I am facing is that when I change the variable named "itemToAdd", the variable named "item" also gets changed. I don't know how to solve this issue.

Anyone help me please, how can I solve it?

Comment: You will need to create a copy of `item`.  There is no general way to do that in Dart, so you will need to do it manually.

Comment: This is my query actually. How to create copy so that changes made in the copied data don't reflect in actual data.

Comment: As I said, there is no general way to do it.  Exactly how you do it depends on whatever type `item` is.  You will need to invoke a constructor for that type and supply the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.